# Picker for optional data type in observable class in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, observable, option-type, picker

I have a very similar problem to [Picker for optional data type in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348093/picker-for-optional-data-type-in-swiftui).

The difference is, that I'm referencing an optional in an obserable class.

My code looks like:

```
enum Flavor: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case chocolate
    case vanilla
    case strawberry

    var id: String { self.rawValue }
}
class cl1: ObservableObject {
    @Published var fl: Flavor?
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedFlavor: cl1 = cl1()
    var body: some View {

        Picker("Flavor", selection: $selectedFlavor.fl) {
            Text("Chocolate").tag(Flavor.chocolate as Flavor?)
            Text("Vanilla").tag(Flavor.vanilla as Flavor?)
            Text("Strawberry").tag(Flavor.strawberry as Flavor?)
        }

            .padding()
    }
}
```

Even though I followed the other answers, as soon as I use a class object it fails.

What do I need to change to make it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using an `ObservableObject`, you should be using a `@StateObject` property wrapper instead of `@State` -- this will allow your `View` to watch for updates on the `@Published` properties of the `ObservableObject`

```
@StateObject private var selectedFlavor: cl1 = cl1()
```

Comment: Correct answer, I forgot it,

Comment: I found: [link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/224/common-swiftui-mistakes-and-how-to-fix-them) also very helpful to gain a better understanding