# swiftui with mixed picker

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to make a mixed picker in swift ui. Means: first part is made of values from a constant, second part is made of core data entity values.

My Code so far

1. Structs

```swift
struct StandardArten: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
}

struct Constants {
    static let standardKontakte = [
        StandardArten(name: "Hausarzt")
    ]
}
```

2. picker

```swift
Picker("Kategorie", selection: $kategorie) {
    Text("Bitte wählen...").tag(Optional<UUID>(nil))
    ForEach(Constants.standardKontakte, id: \.id) { kat in
        Text(kat.name).tag(kat.id)
    }
    Divider()
    ForEach(adressKategorien, id:\.id) { kat in
        Text(kat.name ?? "ohne Titel").tag(kat.id)
    }
}
```

The picker is displayed properly (see image), but selecting "Hausarzt" the picker "jumps back" to the old value.

[image: picker displayed properly]

So what am I doing wrong here?

Additional information:
`$kategorie` is declared as `@State var kategorie: UUID?`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Picker for optional data type in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348093/picker-for-optional-data-type-in-swiftui)

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you. Just as solution posted here: ```Text(kat.name).tag(kat.id as UUID?)``` in standardKontakte does the job