# Why the Picker is not working? Can't select option when I set the @State is optional

Tags: swiftui, picker, swift-optionals

I'm making a picker. When I set the `@State length` to optional, it's not working. I can't select any option.

When I set `@State length` to a Double, it's working. But it associates with another picker. I want that `length` can be nothing, when another picker given some option.

```
//this is DiskLock

struct DiskLock: Identifiable {
    var name: DiskLockName
    var length: Double?
    var actualWeight: Double?
    var id: Int
    
    enum DiskLockName: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
        case standard
        case ledger
        case diagonalBrace
        case headJack
        case baseJack
        var id: Self { self }
    }

}

// two pickers

struct EditDiskLock: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var diskLockViewModel: DiskLockViewModel
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var lengths = [0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 0.2, 0.35, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 1.61, 1.71, 1.86]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                editDiskLockNameSection
                editDiskLockLengthSection
                editDiskLockActualWeightSection
            }
            addDiskLockButton
            Spacer()
        }
        
    }
    
    //selectedDiskLockName
    @State var selectedDiskLockName: DiskLock.DiskLockName = .baseJack
    var editDiskLockNameSection: some View {
        List {
            Picker("DiskLockName", selection: $selectedDiskLockName) {
                ForEach(DiskLock.DiskLockName.allCases) { diskLockName in
                    Text(diskLockName.rawValue)
                }
            }.pickerStyle(.segmented)
        }
    }
    //editDiskLockLengthSection
    @State var selectedDiskLockLength: Double = 0.3 // **i want set this to  optional**
    var editDiskLockLengthSection: some View {
        List {
            Picker("DiskLockLength", selection: $selectedDiskLockLength) {
                if selectedDiskLockName == .standard {
                    ForEach(lengths[3...9], id: \.self) { length in
                        Text(String(length))
                    }
                }
                if selectedDiskLockName == .ledger {
                    ForEach(lengths[0...2], id: \.self) { length in
                        Text(String(length))
                    }
                }
                if selectedDiskLockName == .diagonalBrace {
                    ForEach(lengths[10...12], id: \.self) { length in
                        Text(String(length))
                    }
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(.segmented)
        }
    }
    //editDiskLockActualWeightSection
    @State var actualWeight = ""
    var editDiskLockActualWeightSection: some View {
        Section(header: Text("DiskLockActualWeight")) {
                TextField("DiskLockActualWeight", text: $actualWeight)
        }
    }
    
    //addDiskLockButton
    var addDiskLockButton: some View {
        Button("add") {
            if selectedDiskLockName == .baseJack || selectedDiskLockName == .headJack {
                diskLockViewModel.addNewDiskLock(name: selectedDiskLockName, length: nil, actualWight: Double(actualWeight))
            } else {
                diskLockViewModel.addNewDiskLock(name: selectedDiskLockName, length: selectedDiskLockLength, actualWight: Double(actualWeight))
            }

            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            print("\(diskLockViewModel.diskLocks)")
        }.disabled(selectedDiskLockLength  == 0.3)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348093/picker-for-optional-data-type-in-swiftui
   The `.tag()` (that you should have on your picker `Text(String(length))`) must match the exact data type as the binding is wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

Take one nil value inside your array.
`var lengths = [nil, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 0.2, 0.35, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 1.61, 1.71, 1.86]` and give default value to `Text(String(length ?? 0.0))`

Now make your variable optional `@State var selectedDiskLockLength: Double?`. It will let you select options from picker.

I think the Picker is not updating with optional values, it could be because the selection value is not being set to nil properly.