Can I use .searchScopes with an optional binding?
For my app I'm making a search view. Searching can be done in several scopes with the available scopes being dynamic. When loading the search view the scopes are fetched using an API call, but to do so the selected scopes is an optional. It is unknown which scopes are available so there isn't a selected scope until the fetch is done (the first scope is selected by default). Having an optional selected scope doesn't work, when I make it non-optional by hard coding a value it does work. Is there a way to get .searchSopes working with an optional selection or is there a way to have the selection not be optional when the search scopes are loaded?
struct SearchView: View {
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @State private var searchScopes = [SearchScope]()
    @State private var searchScope: SearchScope?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Text("Searching for \(searchText)")
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText)
        .searchScopes($searchScope, activation: .onSearchPresentation, {
            ForEach(searchScopes) { scope in
                Text(scope.label).tag(scope)
            }
        })
        .task {
            self.searchScopes = await httpClient.fetchSearchScopes()
            if !searchScopes.isEmpty {
                self.searchScope = searchScopes[0]
            }
        }
    }
}


I think this is the common mistake when using an optional selection value type, where you pass the wrong type to tag? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/59348093/5133585

Yep, that's it! When I change Text(scope.label).tag(scope) to Text(scope.label).tag(scope as SearchScope?) it works. I completely missed that. Thanks!

@Sweeper was correct, I made a (common) mistake by passing a non-optional to the .tag() method while the selected search scope is an optional. By casting the search scope in the .tag() method to an optional as suggested in this answer.
ForEach(searchScopes) { scope in
    Text(scope.label).tag(scope as SearchScope?)
}

